# How come the close button on my Modal doesn't appear in mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I am launching my portfolio website at https://johnmurgo.com and when I click to open a project a modal appears. In mobile browsers, when the Modal opens, the close button doesn't appear in the top right as it should. I can still click the area where it should be to close it, but visually the button is not there. I have messed with the z-index but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

When emulating mobile devices in chrome dev tools everything works as it should, but doesn't seem to carry over to actual mobile devices.

```js
const portfolioContainer = document.querySelector(".portfolio-items");

portfolioContainer.addEventListener("click", e => {

    const modalToggle = e.target.closest(".portfolio-link");
      e.preventDefault();

    if(! modalToggle) return;

    const modal = modalToggle.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    const closeButton = modal.querySelector(".modal-close");

    const modalOpen = _ => {
      modal.classList.add("is-open");
      modal.style.animation = "modalFadeIn 250ms forwards";
      document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
    };

    const modalClose = _ => {
      modal.classList.remove("is-open");
      modal.removeEventListener("animationend", modalClose);
    };

    closeButton.addEventListener("click", _ => {
      modal.style.animation = "modalFadeOut 250ms forwards";
      modal.addEventListener("animationend", modalClose);
      document.body.style.overflowY = "scroll";
    });

    document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
      if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) {
        modal.style.animation = "modalFadeOut 250ms forwards";
        modal.addEventListener("animationend", modalClose);
        document.body.style.overflowY = "scroll";
      }
    });

  modalOpen();


});
```

```css
.portfolio {
  background: rgb(125, 125, 125);
}

.portfolio-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 5vh auto 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 5vh;
}

.portfolio-item {
  flex: 1 1 32%;
  grid-column: span 4;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.portfolio-item::before {
    box-shadow: inset 6px 6px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 10%), inset -6px -6px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    top: -1px;
    z-index: 98;
}

.portfolio-item .image-title {
  padding: 2vw;
  background: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.75);
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  transition: top ease-in-out 250ms;
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
  z-index: 99;
}

.portfolio-item:hover .image-title {
  top: 0;
}

.portfolio-item:focus .image-title {
  top: 0;
  outline: none;
}

.continue-button {
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 2vw;
}

.portfolio-title {
  font-size: 4vw;
  line-height: 95%;
}

.portfolio-thumb {
  display: block;
  height: 24vw;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.portfolio-link {
  align-self: flex-start;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2vw;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
}

@supports (display: grid) {
  .portfolio-items {
    display: grid;
    gap: 2vw;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr); }
  }

.portfolio-modal {
  background: white;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 200;
}

.is-open {
  display: block;
}

.modal-close {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  right: 2vw;
  top: 1vw;
  width: 2em;
  z-index: 300;
}

.modal-close:hover .cls-1 {
  fill: rgba(91, 196, 221, 1);
}

.cls-1 {
  fill: rgba(14, 14, 14, 0.5);
  filter: drop-shadow(-1px 1px 1px rgba(14, 14, 14, 0.5))
    drop-shadow(-1px 1px 1px rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.5));
  pointer-events: none;
}

.gray-space::after {
  background: rgb(175, 175, 175);
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 5vw;
  margin-top: 5vw;
  width: 100vw;
}

.white-image::after {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.modal-title-box {
  background: rgb(175, 175, 175);
  color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
  padding: 3vw 12.5vw;
  text-shadow: -1px 1px 1px rgba(14, 14, 14, 0.5),
    1px -1px 1px rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
}

.modal-item-title {
  font-size: 12vw;
}

.modal-subtitle {
  font-size: 5vw;
}

.modal-text-row {
    background: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    padding-bottom: 5vw;
}

.modal-text {
    background: white;
  color: rgb(125, 125, 125);
  font-family: crimson text, serif;
    padding: 0 2vw 0 2vw;
}

.modal-text:nth-child(n+2) {
  padding-top: 2vw;
}

.modal-text:last-of-type {
  padding-bottom: 2vw;
}

.modal-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 5vw auto 0;
}

.modal-item img {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}

.top-borderless {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.portfolio-thin {
  width: 25vw;
}

.portfolio-half {
    margin-top: 5vw;
  width: 35vw;
}

.portfolio-wide {
  width: 45vw;
}

.long-item {
  grid-column: span 12;
  height: auto;
}

@keyframes modalFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes modalFadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <!--Portfolio-->
    <span class="anchor" id="Portfolio"></span>
    <section class="portfolio">
      <h1 class="section-title" id="Portfolio-title">WORK</h1>
      <div class="portfolio-items three-quarter">
        <!---- Portfolio Item 1 ----->
        <div class="portfolio-item">
          <img class="portfolio-thumb" src="assets/images/JustJulezBoxNCards.png" alt="Just Julez logo design">
          <div class="image-title">
            <a href="#" class="portfolio-link">
              <h2 class="portfolio-title">Just Julez </h2>
              <p class="portfolio-description"> Logo Design </p>
              <p class="continue-button">Click to see more</p>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!--- Portfolio Modal 1 ---->
          <div class="portfolio-modal">
            <!--- Close Modal --->
            <button class="modal-close">
              <svg viewBox="0 0 33.71 33.7">
                <defs></defs>
                <g data-name="Layer 2">
                  <g data-name="Layer 1">
                    <path class="cls-1" d="M19.69,16.85,33.12,3.41A2,2,0,0,0,30.29.59L16.85,14,3.41.59A2,2,0,0,0,.59.59a2,2,0,0,0,0,2.82L14,16.85.59,30.28a2,2,0,0,0,0,2.83,2,2,0,0,0,2.82,0L16.85,19.67,30.29,33.11a2,2,0,0,0,1.42.59,2,2,0,0,0,1.41-3.42Z" />
                  </g>
                </g>
              </svg>
            </button>
            <div class="modal-header">
              <div class="modal-title-box">
                <h2 class="modal-item-title"> Just Julez </h2>
                <p class="modal-subtitle"> Logo Design </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-row">
                <img class="modal-item three-quarter" src="assets/images/JustJulezBoxNCards.png" alt="Logo for Just Julez Jewelery Company displayed on box and buisiness card">
              </div>
              <div class="modal-row modal-text-row">
                <p class="modal-item three-quarter modal-text">A local jewelry company was looking for a sassy, feminine logo with a handwritten typeface that would evoke a sense of royalty. The client was heavily inspired by Queen Bees and wanted an illustrated Queen Bee holding a jeweled crown as the focal point of the logo. I presented logos as such, while explaining the importance of keeping the mark simple and bold. We were able to condense the logo to its most important components creating a mark that met the mark.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-row gray-space">
                <div class="modal-item three-quarter">
                  <div class="portfolio-thin">
                    <img src="assets/images/JustJulezCardsMontage-01.png" alt="Montage of buisiness cards for Just Julez Jewelery Company" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="portfolio-wide">
                    <img src="assets/images/JustJulezCard.png" alt="Front of buisiness card for Just Julez Jewelery Company" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!---- Portfolio Item 2 ---->
        <div class="portfolio-item">
          <img class="portfolio-thumb" src="assets/images/SpeakUpLogoOnly.png" alt="Speakup Speakout Identity and promotional materials">
          <div class="image-title">
            <a href="#" class="portfolio-link">
              <h2 class="portfolio-title">Speak Up Speak Out </h2>
              <p class="portfolio-description"> Logo and Promotional Materials </p>
              <p class="continue-button">Click to see more</p>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!--- Portfolio Modal 2 ---->
          <div class="portfolio-modal">
            <!--- Close Modal --->
            <button class="modal-close">
              <svg viewBox="0 0 33.71 33.7">
                <defs></defs>
                <g data-name="Layer 2">
                  <g data-name="Layer 1">
                    <path class="cls-1" d="M19.69,16.85,33.12,3.41A2,2,0,0,0,30.29.59L16.85,14,3.41.59A2,2,0,0,0,.59.59a2,2,0,0,0,0,2.82L14,16.85.59,30.28a2,2,0,0,0,0,2.83,2,2,0,0,0,2.82,0L16.85,19.67,30.29,33.11a2,2,0,0,0,1.42.59,2,2,0,0,0,1.41-3.42Z" />
                  </g>
                </g>
              </svg>
            </button>
            <div class="modal-header header1">
              <div class="modal-title-box">
                <h2 class="modal-item-title"> Speak Up Speak Out </h2>
                <p class="modal-subtitle"> Logo and Promotional Materials </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-row">
                <img class="modal-item three-quarter" src="assets/images/SpeakUpMockupsInplace.png" alt="Logo for Just Julez Jewelery Company displayed on box and buisiness card">
              </div>
              <div class="modal-row modal-text-row">
                <p class="modal-item three-quarter modal-text"> I designed a promotional package for a lecture series, including a poster, a flyer, and a table tent. The goal was to develop a system that could be used amongst multiple topics through the series with minimal effort each week. I first designed the logo and then developed the rest of the system pulling influence from the speech bubble that contains the logo, to create a design that highlights all of the important information in a manner that allows for it to flow and maintain legibility.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-row gray-space">
                <div class="modal-item three-quarter">
                  <div class="portfolio-thin">
                    <img src="assets/images/SpeakUpMockupsInplace.png" alt="Logo for Speak Up Speak out speech series" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="portfolio-wide">
                    <img src="assets/images/SpeakUpMontage.png" alt="Montage of logo, flyer, and poster for speak up speak out speech series" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by changing the width of the .modal-close from  2em to 3em. Not sure what that is about.